# how introduce numbers by keyboard in java

Tags: java, eclipse

What do I have to do in order to introduce numbers by keyboard in Java on eclipse which are the libraries? What is the command to read that? Do I have to write libraries or eclipse do it automatically?

Comment: It's very difficult to understand what you're trying to do and what your question is. You'll get a better response if you could put a little time into making it clearer.

Comment: You mean to receive the values entered by a user using the keyboard? If so you want to make use of the Scanner class

Comment: I want to know how can I introduce numbers by keyboard. for example if i want to do a program to know which is the higher between two numbers inserting the parameters

Comment: You have to make use of event listener in java

Comment: yes I want that entered the values by a user using the keyboard

Comment: So this really has nothing at all to do with Eclipse, right?

Answer (score 1):

This is simple program to get user input
import java.util.Scanner;

```
class GetInputFromUser
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      int a;
      float b;
      String s;

      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter a string");
      s = in.nextLine();
      System.out.println("You entered string "+s);

      System.out.println("Enter an integer");
      a = in.nextInt();
      System.out.println("You entered integer "+a);

      System.out.println("Enter a float");
      b = in.nextFloat();
      System.out.println("You entered float "+b);   
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you were very helpful. I always have to write the librarie, eclipse doesn't import automatically?

Comment: For those libraries in the classpath you can do organize imports by hitting ctrl+shift+o together. Then Eclipse will add the import statements for you. But Eclipse is not able to download missing libraries for you.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're asking how to get a number input from the keyboard in Java...I think...It's hard to understand what you're asking.  If that's what you're asking, well, try this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class InputNumber
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in); 
        int number; 
        System.out.println ("enter a number"); 
        number=in.nextInt(); 
        System.out.println("You entered: " + number);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IO library provided by Java. You need to `import java.io.*` for this.

Create a `BufferedReader` which can take `String` as input. Once a `String` is input, you can parse it to whatever suits you, with a corresponding parser from the wrapper class.

e.g.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
String input = in.readLine();
int num = Integer.parseInt(input);
```